# Quick way to run large sql file containing Insert stms - oracle

Tags: oracle, large-files

I have a sql script that contains 700,000 Insert statements. I tried to run through Oracle Developer, but it failed to load the file itself. I tried to run from sqlplus but its taking quite a long time to execute such large file.

To speed up, I have deleted all the constraints on the table but there is no improvement.

I have looked for information, Please have been suggesting

1. Split the file into manageable sizes - which I will fall back as my last resort.
2. Sql Loader - as far as I understand SQL Loader is to export from the db in specific format and load them into the db with CTL.

Is there any better way to handle this scenario.

Comment: How are you generating the insert script? Are you trying to insert rows from one table to another?

Comment: I received this as data dump for a project

Comment: You could have taken a table dump file and then import it using `IMPDP`. If you have access to the database server, then place the file locally, and use **external table** to load the data. If you need to do it remotely, then use **SQL Loader**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the option 2 is correct.

- Use sed/awk/perl to convert the file into CSV (or fixed width) input file.
- disable constraints, indexes, (possibly drop unique indexes)
- create control file for your input file
- exec `sqlldr` (turn direct path load on)

And this should finish withing few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked. But Due to data inconsistencies I had forgo this option.

Comment: Maybe you also have another problem. Violating PK/FK constraints can also be expensive/slow. Although your whole load possibly runs in a single transaction, the violation of constraint forces statement-only rollback. Maybe load of sane data would be loaded faster, when using any approach.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with previous answer above, 700,000 inserts via script is going to be slow no matter what you do with it - load up your data as an external table or use SQL*Loader.

However

If you want to execute a large script with SQL Developer, don't OPEN the file - we have to open and parse and display the contents of that file. Ow.

Just do this in the worksheet
 @script_name

That will execute the script.

To speed it up even further, hide or minimize the output area of the worksheet.

It's still not going to be super-fast with 700,000 inserts though.

Comment: I have used @script_name through sqlplus, even it did not help. I guess I have to work using sql loader.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the file from many SQL statements to a smaller number of PL/SQL blocks to reduce the round-trip overhead.  This only requires a few minutes with a text editor and can improve performance by orders of magnitude, especially over slow networks.

Every 10,000 lines, add a `begin` and an `end;` to the file.

Change this:

```
insert into ...
insert into ...
insert into ...
...
```

To this:

```
begin
insert into ...
insert into ...
insert into ...
...
end;
/
```

Don't convert the entire file into one large PL/SQL block though.  There is a limit to the size of anonymous PL/SQL blocks, you might get a parser error.

Answer (score 0):

You have also to check if you have some triggers in the table where you are doing the inserts. It can slow down the process if a lot of logic is coded behind.